# Trigger Oracle con sysdate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, trigger

Tengo un trigger en una base de datos simple, lo que quiero que haga ese trigger es generar un id con caracteres y numeros, pero no funciona.

[image: TRIGGER]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, se los agradezco mucho.

[image: DESCRIBE USUARIO]

Comment: ¿el error u obstáculo? En caso que sea ID_USUARIO que no te lo permite, declaralo que permita null; al parecer es lo que estas creando y no tiene caso forzar un valor que "finalmente no quedara guardado".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según veo en tu código, el ID que quieres crear requiere: SYSDATE, USERNAME y PASSWORD. ¿Por qué haces una consulta a la base de datos para obtener esos valores? Los puedes sacar en el trigger usando NEW:[columna] y con eso construir tu id. Si notas, el error que te aparece es un "no data found". Tiene sentido porque estás consultando con el select registros de una tabla que supongo está vacía. Incluso si tuviera registros sería erróneo porque si hay varios registros no puedes usar el "select .. into".

Answer (score 0):

Yo realizo un insert a la tabla USUARIO

[image: CONSULTA]

Y me bota el siguiente error

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente Mauricio, me percaté de que faltaba usar :NEW en USERNAME y PASSWORD, además gracias a tu respuesta, usé el SELECT en DUAL y logré insertar.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]